# Server response "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double"

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm trying to make post request using `NSURLSession`. I need to send data which includes double values. I used `NSNumber` to store double values inside `NSDictionary`. I am posting data like this:

```
 -(void)sortJobsWithLat:(float)lat longt:(float)longt distance:(float)distance budget:(NSInteger)budget rating:(NSInteger)rating page:(NSUInteger)page {

    NSError *error;
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BaseURLJobs,SearchJobs]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSLog(@"url : %@", url);

      NSDictionary *params=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat] ,@"latitude",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:longt],@"longitude", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance],@"distance",   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)budget] ,@"budget", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)rating],@"rating", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",page],@"pageNo",nil];

    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:kNilOptions error:&error];


    NSLog(@"params : %@",params);

    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                    if(error == nil)
                                    {
                                        NSError *jsonError;
                                        NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                                                                     error:&jsonError];
                                        NSLog(@"json object : %@",jsonObject);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        [AppDel showAlertWithMessage:error.localizedDescription andTitle:nil];
                                    }
                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

When I print params using `NSLog`, It prints like this:

```
    params : {
    budget = 1000;
    distance = 50;
    latitude = "30.73979949951172";
    longitude = "76.78269958496094";
    pageNo = 0;
    rating = 4;
}
```

Server is returning response like:

```
json object : {
    error = "Internal Server Error";
    exception = "java.lang.ClassCastException";
    message = "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double";
    path = "/jobs/searchJobs";
    status = 500;
    timestamp = 1471760398842;
}
```

This error is clearly showing server is not able to caste integer value to double.I'm getting this error due to distance parameter. I'm passing distance as double value then how server is finding it as integer value?

The problem is that those parameters are not recognized by the server. The server part works correctly because I've sent a POST using Swagger UI for Google Chrome and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Update your question with your actual code for making the post request. Update your question with the actual problem you having when making the post request.

Comment: I have updated code, Please check it. If it is still unclear then let me know..

Comment: You have bad server code.

Comment: I'm getting this error cause distance is integer value and server is not able to cast it to double...

Comment: Fix your server.  It's braindead.

Comment: The exception happens on the server, in Java code. And you're showing us client code, in what I guess is Objective C.

Comment: Please mention reason when you down vote. It will help me to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this error because I was sending 50.0 as double value. Objective C converts it to integer automatically. So server was getting integer value and it was unable to cast this value. I have made changes on server to solve this error..